# Requirements for building the android platform not satisfied

Tags: android, cordova

I'm a newcomer to the Cordova world, so I'm attempting to build and run my first app. To do so, I'm following the steps set out in the official Cordova page but I'm getting an error at the build stage.

Apparently, the android platform is added successfully:

```
D:\Users\user\workspace\cordova\helloworld>cordova platform add android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.3.0
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: com.example.helloworld
        Name: HelloWorld
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-26
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.3.0
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.
--save flag or autosave detected
Saving android@~6.3.0 into config.xml file ...
```

But when I check if the pre-requisites for the build stage are met, I get the following error:

```
D:\Users\user\workspace\cordova\helloworld>cordova requirements
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: "avdmanager" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Gradle\gradle-4.3.1\bin\gradle
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

I don't just understand how is it possible no Android target is installed as long as the `cordova platform add android` command worked successfully. What am i doing wrong?

I've got the following tools installed (Windows 7 x64):

1. JDK 1.8.0
2. Android SDK 25.2.5
3. Gradle 4.3.1
4. Node 8.9.1
5. Cordova 7.1.0

I think the environment variables are set ok:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
GRADLE_PATH=C:\Program Files\Gradle\gradle-4.3.1
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152
Path= ... ; C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
      D:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;
      C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin;
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;
      C:\Program Files\Gradle\gradle-4.3.1\bin
```

I'd like to say that I didn't install Android Studio as I prefer to use eclipse+ADT plugin. To install the Android SDK tool I got from the Internet an installer .exe (version 24.4.1) which got updated automatically on first run. Current version of Android SDK, and as I said, is 25.2.5. From the Android SDK Manager I installed API levels 21 - 26, which I can see within the ANDROID_HOME\platforms (android-21, android-22, ..., android-26 folders).

Any explanation about what is happening would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: try installing cordova-android 6.4.0 with `cordova platform add android@6.4.0`. As it was a minor bump the current CLI doesn't install it as it has ~6.3.0 pinned.

Comment: Neither 6.4.0 nor 7.0.0 version worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the target api  version in manifest file, project. properties in platform folder (android)and project.properties in Cordovalib folder

Comment: Nowadays, in _/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml_, `android:targetSdkVersion="26"`. In _/platforms/android/CordovaLib/AndroidManifest.xml_, there is no `android:targetSdkversion` attribute. Both in _/platforms/android/project.properties_, and _/platforms/android/CordovaLib/project.properties_, `target=android-26`. What values should they have?

Comment: Try cordova platform remove android and then cordova platform add android@6.0.0  .This will take target 24 which u already have .Maybe it may work

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083924/avdmanager-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-cordova]  may be this can help

Comment: Since I already have android-26 platform installed, the command `cordova platform add android` will take target 26 and it should therefore work. But it doesn't. And I've tried that command with an emulated device targeting API level 26, but it doesn't work. Frustrating...