# Info about 'cordova platform add android' command

Tags: android, cordova

I'm a newcomer to the Cordova development world and I feel somewhat confused about the `cordova platform add android` command.
In a command like `cordova platform add android@version`, I don't know what is the relation between the specified 'version' and the targeted android platform. The command `cordova platform add android` (that is `cordova platform add android@6.3.0`), targets android-26 platform (that is, the platform intended for Android 8.0.0 OS with API level 26).
Or am I completely wrong? Any clarification would be pretty appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relationship between them

When you add the platform with a version you specify a cordova-android version from the [released ones](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/releases). If you don't specify one, it will install the version pinned on the Cordova CLI (or higher patch version if available). Again, the Cordova CLI version has no relationship with cordova-android version or Android targeted version.

cordova-android uses semver for it's versions, that is, major.minor.patch

When there is a breaking change, the first number is changed, and changing the target SDK is not always a breaking change.

All the platform updates are announced on the [Cordova blog](http://cordova.apache.org/blog/), make sure you read it frequently so you can be informed of new CLI, platforms and plugins releases

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and for the useful links. I knew what `Cordova CLI` version was, and now I know what `cordova-android` and `android-targeted` versions are.

Comment: I'd really thank you if you could provide an evaluation on the problem I have explained in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379806/requirements-for-building-the-android-platform-not-satisfied/47407224?noredirect=1#comment81910503_47407224