# avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu-18.04

I've been trying to configure Apache Cordova for some time on Ubuntu-18.04, I've researched a lot about this error, but no solution helped me.

When I run `$cordova requirements`, I get this as a result:

```
Android Studio project detected  
Requirements check results for android:  
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0  
Android SDK: installed true  
Android target: not installed   
avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1  
Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle  
Some of requirements check failed
```

When I run `echo $PATH`, I get this:

```
/home/marcos/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/bin/java:/home/marcos/Android/Sdk:/home/marcos/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/marcos/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/marcos/Documents/apache-ant-1.9.13/bin:/usr/bin/java:/home/marcos/Android/Sdk:/home/marcos/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/marcos/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

So, I know all things are set on the `$PATH`, but I still getting this error, I already check everything on Android Studio, all tools are there, I can even emulate a device there, but I can't run Cordova by the command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1 cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083924/avdmanager-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-cordova)